# Accessing google places rating image url

Tags: google-places-api

The Yelp API can return not just a numeric rating but an image so you can show a yelp-branded review image (rating_img_url shows partial stars, etc.)

Is it possible to do the same with Google?  The API docs reference the old 0-5 ranking:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceDetailsResults

Current Google places results show "Score: Overall" followed by 0-30 see:
https://plus.google.com/local/San%20Francisco,%20CA/s/starbucks%20market?gl=us&hl=en

Is there a currently recommended/approved approach to access the rating and show an appropriate image?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Places API does not currently support these features. Please submit a [Places API - Feature Request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request) to let us know so that we can provide it for you.

There is currently no recommended/approved way to show a rating image for the Google Places API. You are free to use whatever method you feel works with you application.